# How can I extract colours from a palette band to create seperate layers?

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, land-use, palette

I downloaded land use maps of Australia as TIFF files. Since the country is very large (and the map is very detailed), I had to download multiple files that align together. I want to make separate maps/layers for each land use. However, the 11 land uses are classified in 1 palette band. Thereby I also run into the problem that the different files (rasters) have different EPSG's. This made it impossible for me to combine them in 1 virtual raster.
I added a picture in case this helps to visualize the situation.

How can I extract the land uses to make 1 layer per land use and also do this for entire Australia?

FYI I work in QGIS 3.34.2
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to link to the Land Use data.

Comment: You can use the ArcGIS REST service directly in QGIS https://www.environment.gov.au/mapping/rest/services/abares/NLUM_250m/MapServer